# Why doesn't Base 64 decoding convert to bytes as expected?

Tags: binary, base64, bit

Given the base 64 string `A/==` this decodes to `00000011`.

However, according to the [Base 64 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-4), `A` translates to binary `000000` and `/` translates to binary `111111`. Together, this would be `000000111111`, not what I have above.

I understand that to represent it in bytes, it would need padding, so `0000001111110000` would make sense to me, but it actually chops off the end (`1111`), why is this?

(I've tried this against both C# and Python's implementation for Base64 conversions.)

Comment: *this decodes to 00000011* - as I would expect it.  - *this would be 000000111111* - these are 12 bits, but a byte has only 8 bits. -  *0000001111110000 would make sense to me* - no, where should the last for bits come from? - *but it actually chops off the end (1111), why is this?* - because the last 4 bits are not enough to fill a byte. Abase64 decoder decodes to bytes And if on the end there are 2 or 4 bytes left, they're truncated.